# AJAX DISPLAY PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I come to you, car I have unins, I can not display a page.php dynamically without reloading the page.

I explain to you the concept, I have a menu, and from this menu I want that as soon as I click on a topic its load my page.php and I display it dynamically without reloading it. I tried ajax but I can not

page.php :

```
    <?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this'){
@session_start();
include ('db_connect.php');
 include('function.php');
$chainefinal = explode ('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
/*-------------------------------------------------Initialisation des variables---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$t1=$t2=$t3=$t4=$top=$output=$ligne1=$ligne2=$final='';
$total_sheduled_fr=$total_sheduled_de=$total_sheduled_fr_FMS=$total_sheduled_fr_CPT=$total_sheduled_de_FMS=$total_sheduled_de_CPT= 0;
$current_h = date("H");

/************************************************SELECTION JOURS, MOIS, ANNEE *******************************************************************/

 //$annee_selectionne = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y');
 //var_dump($annee_selectionne);
 //$mois_selectionne = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m');
 // $jour_selectionne = isset($_GET['day']) ? $_GET['day'] : date('d');
 // var_dump($jour_selectionne);

    $date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime("this thursday UTC"));
    $date1 = split('/', $date);

    $annee_selectionne = $date1[0];
    // var_dump($annee_selectionne);
    $mois_selectionne = $date1[1];
    // var_dump($mois_selectionne);
    $jour_selectionne = $date1[2];
    // var_dump($jour_selectionne);

    $today = date("jS F, Y", strtotime("this monday UTC")); 
    $today1 = date("jS F, Y", strtotime("this tuesday UTC"));
    $today2 = date("jS F, Y", strtotime("this wednesday UTC"));
    $today3 = date("jS F, Y", strtotime("this thursday UTC"));
    $today4 = date("jS F, Y", strtotime("this friday UTC"));

  ################################################ Initialisation de nouvelle variable ###############################

    $tday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mois_selectionne, $jour_selectionne , $annee_selectionne);
    $change_limit = mktime(date("H"), 0, 0, date("m"), (date("d") + 6), date("y"));
    $search_date = $annee_selectionne.'-'.$mois_selectionne.'-'.$jour_selectionne;

    // a garder -->  $search_date_plus_5_jours = strtotime("today + 5 days ");
    // echo strtotime("today + 5 days "), "\n";
    // a garder --> echo $search_date_plus_5_jours;  


/*--------------------------------------------FORMAT HEURE CALENDRIER EN HAUT TABLEAU -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $requette = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM trainning_format WHERE trainning_date = \''.$search_date.'\'');
    $debut =8;
    $fin=18;

/***************************  Affichage heure haut du tableau *****************************/

 if (!$data = $requette->fetch())
      {
         $requette = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM trainning_format WHERE trainning_date < \''.$search_date.'\'');
         $data = $requette->fetch();
         $debut = 8;
         $fin = 18;

     }
 else
    {
        if ( $data['trainning_format'] == 1)
            {
                $debut = 8;
                $fin = 18;
            }
        else
            {
                $debut = 6;
                $fin = 22;
            }
    }
  $requette->closecursor();

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------- en tete du planning ----------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/****************************** Commencement et fin des lignes du tableu(heure) **************************/
for ($h = ($debut - 1);$h <= ($fin + 1);$h++)
    {
        $ligne1 .= '<td colspan="4" class="emptyhead">
                    '.$h.'<br />|
                    </td>
                    ';  
    }

    /****************************** Commencement et fin des lignes en blanc **************************/
for ($h = ($debut - 1);$h <= ($fin+2);$h=$h+0.25)
    {
        if ($h == ($current_h + 0.75) AND $jour_selectionne == date("d"))
            {
                $ligne2 .= '<td class="smallplanningnow">....</td>
                    ';
            }
        else
            {
                $ligne2 .= '<td class="smallplanning">....</td>
                ';
            }
    }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------- colone de STH -------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if (isset($_SESSION['droit']) and $_SESSION['droit'] == 5 or $_SESSION['droit'] == 2)
    {
        $ligne1 .= '<td>GE</td>
                    <td>FR</td>';
        $ligne2 .= '<td class="smallplanning">....</td>
                    <td class="smallplanning">....</td>';
    }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------- Fin colone de STH -----------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$ligne_H =$ligne1.'</tr><tr>'.$ligne2.'</tr>
            </thead>';

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------- Affichage SIMULATEUR T1 ; T2 ; T3 ; T4 ------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

for ($b = 1;$b <= 4;$b++)
    {
        $requette   =   $bdd->query('   SELECT simulator.building_id, level_1.name
                                    FROM simulator, level_1
                                    WHERE level_1.id = simulator.building_id
                                    AND simulator.building_id = '.$b);
        $building = $requette->fetch();
        $tranche = $building['name'];
        $requette->closecursor();

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------- Affichage du planning ----------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $output .='<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <td class="build2">
                                '.$tranche.'
                            </td>'.$ligne_H.'<tbody>';

        $requette   =   $bdd->query('   SELECT simulator.*, kit.kit_name
                                        FROM simulator, kit
                                        WHERE kit.id = simulator.kit
                                        AND simulator.building_id = '.$b.'
                                        ORDER BY efa_name DESC');

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------- Affichage des noms de simulateurs ----------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        while ($sim =   $requette->fetch())
            {
                $cabtype = substr($sim['kit_name'],0, 1);  /* --> Affichage lettre P & G */
                $req = $bdd->query('SELECT nation
                                    FROM four_week_planning
                                    WHERE simulator_id = '.$sim['id'].'
                                    AND planning_date = \''.$search_date.'\'');

                if($don = $req->fetch())
                    {
                        $nation = $don['nation'];
                        $req->closecursor();
                    }
                /*------------------- si rien dans la bdd à cette date -------------*/
                else
                    {
                        $reqs = $bdd->query('   SELECT nation FROM four_week_planning
                                                WHERE simulator_id = '.$sim['id'].'
                                                AND planning_date < \''.$search_date.'\'
                                                ORDER BY planning_date DESC LIMIT 0,1');
                        $dons = $reqs->fetch();
                        $nation = $dons['nation'];
                        $reqs->closecursor();
                    }
                $req->closecursor();

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------- Affichage des DRAPEAU DE ET FR -------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                switch($nation)
                    {
                        case 1:$class = 'class="de"';$nat = 0;break;
                        case 2:$class = 'class="fr"';$nat = 2;break;
                        case 3:$class = 'class="de_disable"';$nat = 3;break;
                        case 4:$class = 'class="fr_disable"';$nat = 3;break;
                        default:$class = '';$nat = 0;break;
                    }


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------- Affichage Icone tableau ; Class = drapeau ; sim = nom du simu ; cab = P ou G ----------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                $output .= '    <tr class="">
                                <td '.$class.'  >
                                    '.$sim['stpname'].'<br />'.$cabtype.'
                                </td>
                            ';
                $h = $debut - 1.25;
                $debut_sec = ($debut - 1.5) * 3600;
                $f = $fin + 1.5;
                $first = 'first';
                while ($h <= $f)
                    {

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------- Récupération de la valeur du champ heure (7 ; 7.15 ; 7.30 ; 7.45 ; 8 ect ... ----------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                        $c = $h - 0.25 ;
                        $minutage = $h - intval($h);
                        if($minutage != 0)
                            {
                                switch($minutage)
                                    {
                                        case 0.25:$minute = 15;break;
                                        case 0.50:$minute = 30;break;
                                        case 0.75:$minute = 45;break;

                                    }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $minute = 0;
                            }
                        $current_time = mktime(intval($h), $minute, 0, $mois_selectionne, $jour_selectionne, $annee_selectionne);
                        if(isset($_SESSION['droit']) AND (($_SESSION['droit'] >= 2 AND $current_time >= $change_limit AND $_SESSION['nation'] == $nat) OR $_SESSION['droit'] >= 2))
                            {
                                $edit_add ='<a href="javascript:openPlanningPopUp(\'simplaninng/index.php\',\''.$sim['id'].'\',\''.$c.'\',\''.$jour_selectionne.'\',\''.$mois_selectionne.'\',\''.$annee_selectionne.'\')">&otimes;</a>';
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $edit_add ='';
                            }
                        if ( is_int($h) AND $jour_selectionne == date("d"))
                            {
                                $cur_class = 'emptybodyT';
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $cur_class = 'emptybody';
                            }
                        $heure = $tday + $debut_sec ;
                        $req    =   $bdd->query('   SELECT simplanning.*,tigerUsers.trigramme
                                                    FROM simplanning,tigerUsers
                                                    WHERE simplanning.sim_id = '.$sim['id'].'
                                                    AND simplanning.date_start ='.$heure.'
                                                    AND tigerUsers.id=simplanning.user_id');

                        if($simuse =$req->fetch())

                            {

                                $fi = $simuse['date_end'];
                                $deb = $simuse['date_start']; 
                                $delta = ($fi - $deb) / 900;

                                /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                                /*-------------------------- calcul sth day-----------------------------*/
                                /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                                if ($simuse['trainning_type'] != 7 AND $simuse['trainning_type'] != 10 AND $simuse['trainning_type'] != 11 AND $simuse['trainning_type'] != 17 AND $simuse['trainning_type'] != 12 AND $simuse['trainning_type'] != 13 AND $simuse['use_mode'] == 1)
                                    {
                                        $deta = ($fi - $deb);
                                        if ($nat == 2)
                                            {
                                                $total_sheduled_fr = $total_sheduled_fr + $deta;
                                                $total_sheduled_de = 0;
                                            }
                                        else
                                            {
                                                $total_sheduled_de = $total_sheduled_de + $deta;
                                                $total_sheduled_fr = 0;
                                            }
                                    }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------- Affichage de la fédération qui utilise le simulateur  ---------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                                $vdb = display_vdb($simuse['request_vdb']);     /* vdb = visuel data base = le luc --> fonction.php */
                                $type = trainning_type($simuse['trainning_type'],'type',$simuse['use_mode']);
                                $classmode = trainning_type($simuse['trainning_type'],'class',$simuse['use_mode']);
                                if ($type == 'Del.')
                                    {
                                        $type .=' the '.date_format(date_create($simuse['last_update']), 'd-m H:i');    
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $type .= '<br /><font size="-5">'.$vdb.'</font>';
                                    }
                                if ($simuse['request_mode'] == 2)
                                    {
                                         $classmode = $classmode.'coupled';
                                    }
                                 switch($simuse['fede_wan_amtlt'])
                                     {
                                         case 0 : $type .= '';break;
                                         case 1 : $type .= '<br /><a class="opt">Fede</a>';break;
                                         case 2 : $type .= '<br /><a class="opt">Wan</a>';break;
                                         case 3 : $type .= '<br /><a class="opt">AMTLT</a>';break;
                                         case 4 : $type .= '<br /><a class="opt">R.IOS</a>';break;
                                     }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------- Si on a les droits alors on peut modifié ou supprimer un training  --------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                                if(isset($_SESSION['droit']) AND (($_SESSION['droit'] >= 2 AND $_SESSION['nation'] == $nat AND $current_time >= $change_limit) OR $_SESSION['droit'] >= 2))
                                    {
                                        $edit_add ='<div class="plan_edit"></div>';
                                        $dele = '<div class="plan_delete"><a href="javascript:PlanningDeletPopUp(\''.$simuse['id'].'\')" >&otimes;</a></div>';

                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $edit_add ='';
                                        $dele = '';
                                    }
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------Bouton Modifier et Delete  -------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                                $output .= '    <td colspan="'.$delta.'" class="'.$classmode.'" title="Add by: '.$simuse['trigramme'].' '.(($simuse['last_update']!=$simuse['input_date'])?'updated on '.$simuse['last_update']:'Add on '.$simuse['input_date']).'">
                                                <div>'.$edit_add.''.$dele.'</div>
                                                '.$type.'
                                                <br />'.$simuse['commentaire'].'
                                            </td>'; 
                                $debut_sec = $debut_sec + (900 * ($delta + 1));
                                $h = $h + (0.25 * ($delta + 1) ) ;

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------ Reservation 15 min apres le training pour la maintenance ; MENU a gauche  -----------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                                if ($h == $current_h+0.5 AND $jour_selectionne == date("d"))
                                    {
                                        $output .= '<td class="'.$cur_class.'now"></td>
                                        ';
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $output .= '<td class="'.$cur_class.'"></td>
                                        ';
                                    }
/********************************************************************************************************************/                                      
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                if ($h == $current_h+0.25 AND $jour_selectionne == date("d"))
                                    {
                                        $output .= '<td class="'.$cur_class.'now">'.$edit_add.'</td>
                                        ';
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        $output .= '<td class="'.$cur_class.'">'.$edit_add.'</td>
                                        ';
                                    }
                                $debut_sec = $debut_sec + 900;
                                $h = $h + 0.25;
                            }
                        $req->closecursor();
                    }

                /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                /*---------------------------- colone de STH -------------------------------------*/
                /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                if (isset($_SESSION['droit']) and $_SESSION['droit'] == 5 or $_SESSION['droit'] == 2)
                    {
                        $output .= '<td class="emptyhead">'.affich_heure(($total_sheduled_de)/ 3600 ).'</td>';
                        $output .= '<td class="emptyhead">'.affich_heure(($total_sheduled_fr)/ 3600 ).'</td>';
                    }
                $total_sheduled_fr = 0;
                $total_sheduled_de = 0;

                /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                /*-------------------------- fin colone de STH -----------------------------------*/
                /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                 $output .= '</tr>
                 ';
            }
        $requette->closecursor();
        $output .='</table>';
        if ($b != 5)
            {
                $output .= '<br />';
            }
        $final .= $output;
        $output ='';
    }
?>
<style type="text/css">   

ul#menu_horizontal li { 
display : inline;
padding : 0 0.5em; /* Pour espacer les boutons entre eux */

}
ul#menu_horizontal {
list-style-type : none; /* Car sinon les puces se placent n'importe où */
} 
</style>
<h1 id="D4"> <?php echo $today3; ?></h1>

<ul id="menu_horizontal">

<li><a href="#D1"><?php echo $today ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#D2"><?php echo $today1 ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#D3"><?php echo $today2 ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#D4"><?php echo $today3 ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#D5"><?php echo $today4 ?></a></li>

</ul>
 <div class="plansimcalendar" id="test2">
    <?/*php/* include ('C_User_file/calendar.php');*/?>
</div> 
<br /><br />
<!--<div class="simplanning_left">
    <a href="index.php?action=simplan&day=<?php echo $jour_link_moins;?>&month=<?php echo $mois_link_moins;?>&year=<?php echo $annee_link_moins;?>">-</a>
</div>-->
<div class="simplanning_center">
<!-- <a href="simplaninng/filesimplanning.php">&otimes;</a> -->
<?php echo $final; ?>
</div>
<!--<div class="simplanning_right">
    <a href="index.php?action=simplan&day=<?php echo $jour_link_plus;?>&month=<?php echo $mois_link_plus;?>&year=<?php echo $annee_link_plus;?>">+</a>
</div>-->

}
```

Ajax :

```
    <script>
  function myAjax(){
   $.ajax({
       type= "POST",
  url: 'index.php?action=simplan3",
  datatype: 'json',
  data: {action:'call_this'},
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').php(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
  }


  </script>
  <div id="result">

  </div>
<li><a href="#D2" id="merde" onclick="myAjax()"><?php echo $today1 ?></a></li>
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Is `$('#result').php(data);` a existing function? If no, then try to use `.text(data)` or `.html(data)`

Comment: @C0dekid I have already tried .html and .text, still nothing

Comment: also `type="POST"` should be `type: "POST"`

Comment: When I click on my li, the ajax does not load, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistake in your ajax call:

```
    <script>
      function myAjax(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST", //not type= "POST"
      url: 'index.php?action=simplan3',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {action:'call_this'},
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);//or $('#result').text(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });
return false; // just outside the ajax call would help you i guess
      }    
      </script>
```

I found the issue: in ajax call double quote is used which was causing error. check below:

```
  url: 'index.php?action=simplan3",
```

changed to

```
  url: 'index.php?action=simplan3',
```

Comment: what you are getting in ajax success: data could paste it here? i edited the code and added return false just after the ajax call. hope it would be helpful

Comment: When I click on my li, the ajax does not load, nothing happens

Comment: 1. when you click on the link alert message is coming? 2. if yes then check ajax call is working by pressing F12 button for developer console and check response. maybe your ajax call is not working

Comment: After my function myAjax, I added alert ('ok') there is nothing happening, so when I click there is nothing happening

Comment: Hey, there was code error of **double quotes**, check the code edited. Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I just solved my problems but also thanks to your help, I explain the error, ajax does not like this url it wants a real url for example page.php or page.html and no page with a redirection As I had put. Second point the ajax did not launch because I had put a href with an anchor of the blow the function does not launch but it is a bit boring must I find like saying to him of the function despite that it is an anchor . And third point, my php file had include files and needed to be replaced by require_once ('../../ function.php'); Here are all the problems solved!

Comment: On the other hand it annoys me for the anchor perhaps an idea?

Comment: It need not be anchor tag if you don't need it just replace it with span tag or place onclick on li tag itself. For your information: href wont hurt the call. It must be something else

Answer (score 1):

You should add `return false;` in your ajax function this will prevent the page from reload.

Here a exemple of implementation:

```
<script>
$("form").submit(function(){
        //alert("Submitted");
        //prevent from redirect
        return false;
    });



  </script>
```

Comment: `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }` would do it's job better.

Comment: $('form').submit() !== $('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()});